Conditional expectations preserve convergence in measure
Suppose that $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of random variables defined on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and $\mathcal{G}\subseteq\mathcal{F}$ be a sub-$\sigma-$algebra. Then in class we have done that if $X_n\uparrow X$ P-a.e then $\mathbb{E}(X_n|\mathcal{G})\uparrow\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{G})$ P-a.e.
I would like to know if this statement can be generalized to the following:
If $X_n\to X$ P-a.e then $\mathbb{E}(X_n|\mathcal{G})\to\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{G})$ P-a.e.
So, is monotonicity necessary for the result? I don't think it is necessary but I am unable to prove. I also can't think of a counterexample if it isn't. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Easy counter-example: Suppose $X$ and $X_n$ are independent of $\mathcal G$. Then you are asking if $X_n \to X$ a.s. implies $EX_n \to EX$. A standard counter-example is $X_n=n1_{(0,\frac1 n)}, X=0$ on $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure.  To get independence in this example, you can take $\mathcal G=\{\emptyset, (0,1)\}$.
Recall that $E(X|\mathcal G)=EX$ if $X$ is independent of $\mathcal G$.

Thank you for your answer. But in your counterexample, we do not have $X_n\to X$ in measure in $L_1(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. We only seem to have that $X_n$ converges to $X$ in $L_1(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, P)$. Maybe I misunderstood. Could explain where I am going wrong in understanding the counterexample.

@naveenraj03 Your question is: If $X_n\to X$ P-a.e then $\mathbb{E}(X_n|\mathcal{G})\to\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{G})$ P-a.e. In my example, $X_n \to X$ at every point of $(0,1)$ so $X_n\to X$ P-a.e. I am using the fact that $E(X|\mathcal G)=EX$ and $E(X_n|\mathcal G)=EX_n$ for every $n$ because of independence.

I think I understand your example. Thank you. What would $E(X_n|\mathcal{G})$ equal in this example? Shouldn't the answer equal a measurable function? what is that function?

$X_n$ is also independent of $\mathcal G$ so $E(X_n|\mathcal G)=EX_n$. @naveenraj03
